# Embedding binary video data in a swf file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, flv, embedding

Is it possible to play video from data that has been embedded in a swf at compile time (with the `[Embed]` metatag)?

The "Import Video->Embed" feature provided by Flash CS3 etc. is not acceptable because it has many severe limitations (including sound synchronization issues, a maximum number of frames, and other caveats)

I'm interested in being able to bundle flv video data in a swf (along with other assets), which will be played by an AIR application.

I don't think it can be done. Anyone disagree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as your video is an FLV, then the answer is yes - you can use `NetStream.appendBytes()` to play the embedded `ByteArray`:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    [Embed(source="sample.flv", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
    private var SampleVideo:Class;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        var video:Video = new Video(320, 240);
        addChild(video);

        var netConnection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        netConnection.connect(null);
        var netStream:NetStream = new NetStream(netConnection);
        netStream.client = {};
        video.attachNetStream(netStream);

        var byteArray:ByteArray = new SampleVideo();
        netStream.play(null);
        netStream.appendBytes(byteArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! And since FP 10.1! How did I miss that?! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can import a flv into a swf file using the Flash IDE - I've done that before. You can drop it onto the timeline of a MovieClip just like a sound and then drop that movieclip onto the stage for it to play. In Flash CS3 do File>Import>Import Video and select the flv. Choose the video and then on the next stop of the wizard choose "Embed ..... ", Here is a link to an [Adobe Developer center article on embedding flvs into swfs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/video_guide_02.html#embedding).

I have not done so myself, but I can see no reason why you could access the flv from the library of a loaded swf.

FYI: It looks like this was a bug that was deferred. It doesn't look like Adobe currently allows embedding using the Embed meta tag. Here is a [forum post](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=274183) on the issue and a link to the [bug tracker](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-259).

Comment: Unfortunately that approach has a lot of caveats which I can't live with. The biggest one is the sound synchronization issue, but there are also framecount restrictions and other misc limitations. 

I've updated the question. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Thanks for those links James, especially the kirupa.com thread. Makes me feel less insane.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to embed video into SWFs with the Flash IDE but it's not a very good option:

> *"Playback is limited to simple play and stop commands, and the video
>   framerate must match that of the host
>   movie, an important consideration that
>   will require authoring for the
>   lowest-common-denominator download
>   speed."*
>
> *"The biggest limitations to embedded
>   video are movies having a maximum of
>   16,000 frames and audio sync cannot be
>   maintained beyond about two minutes."*

Those quotes are from [this article](http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_14571). It's a bit old but as far as I know, what is said there about embedding video still holds true.

Comment: That's a very good point. I know the "Import Video->Embed" feature of Flash CS3, but it's not an acceptable solution for those reasons.

I'm looking out for _another_ way to embed video. I was imagining something like instantiating an `[Embed]`ed class and passing it to the video player.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah, so apparently you can embed binary data in a swf using the `Embed` meta tag.

```
[Embed(
    source="local_data_file.flv",
    mimeType="application/octet-stream") ]
private static var __FlvClass123:Class;
protected static var flvData:ByteArray = new __FlvClass123();
```

Whether you can playback embedded video from a ByteArray or not is not something I cannot answer one way or another at this stage ...

Answer (score 0):

just had the same problem and searched for a more "flex"ible solution.
seems these Days dynamic embedding works perfectly simple:

```
public function loadSWF(){

 var _assetLdr:Loader;
_assetLdr = new Loader();
_assetLdr.load(new URLRequest("1.swf"));
_assetLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.handleComplete);
addChild(_assetLdr); 
}


public function handleComplete(event:Event):void {

    trace("complete");
    var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo=event.target as LoaderInfo;
    var content:MovieClip = loaderInfo.loader.content as MovieClip;
    addChild(content);

}
```

Note: Check the screen offsets within the `library.swf`. In my case they were messed up, so it simply displayed offscreen. (ThankGodForCoffee)
Have a nice Day!

Comment: Woah. You say "these days"? Flash still ... like... exists? You're blowing my mind!

Comment: Also, my question actually stipulated embedding, whereas this solution is a runtime download of the movie file, unless I'm missing something.