# Is it possible to embed flv file in to flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flv, flvplayback, flash-cs5

Is it possible to embed the flv file in to the flash like other files(images, swf), so that i can handle this in as3 as programmaticaly in the same way as FLVPlayback component? I know the way to add flv file by creating FLVPlayback component. But in this case we always need to depend on the source path of corresponding file. I am not able to find any kind of solution for this. As second way I have imported flv file to the library and created the instance of this but there is some problem with the synchronization of audio with video. Also in this case I am not able to handle this flv in as3 as programmatically.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is possible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199068/embedding-binary-video-data-in-a-swf-file

Answer (score 0):

read next things:

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=123832

http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=853#comment-253072

if you want some help, post the source you have, so community could provide the snippets for you goals.

Regards
Eugene

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use the [Video class](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Video.html), there is a simple example at the bottom of the page showing how to set up Netstreams and Netconnections.